# Why does all work for a regular list and not a 2d one?

Tags: python, list

```
grid = [[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]]

if all(x in grid for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):
    print('yes')
```

This doesn't print anything when tried however when I do the same with a normal list containing the numbers 1 through 9 it prints just fine. How would I check if the values 1 through 9 are contained within a 2d list?

Answer (score 4):

You can either [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) the `grid` and then search:

```py
flattened_grid = [item for sub_list in grid for item in sub_list]

if all(x in flattened_grid for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):
    print("yes")
```

or you can check if `x` is `in` [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the sublists:

```py
if all(any(x in sub_list for sub_list in grid) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):
    print("yes")
```

The reason why `all`-only way doesn't work is: you are checking `x`, which is an integer, against lists; but they will never compare equal and `in` will be `False` for each check.

Answer (score 1):

**Try flattening the list**

Here's an example using the [method from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

```
def check_2d_list(t: list):
    flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
    return all(x in flat_list for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

grid = [[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]] 

if check_2d_list(grid):
    print("Yes")
```